# Try Catch keeps looping instead of asking for another value?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
Scanner inputSide = new Scanner(System.in);

double side[] = new double[3];
int i = 0;
do{
    try{
    System.out.println("Enter three side lengths for a triangle (each followed by pressing enter):");
    side[i] = inputSide.nextDouble();
    i++;
    }
    catch(Exception wrongType){
        System.err.println(wrongType);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number.  Start again!!");
        i=0;
    }
}
while(i<3);
```

It works fine and does what it's meant to if I don't enter a wrong data type but if I enter something other than a double then it loops over and over, printing everything in both try and catch blocks instead of waiting for me to enter another double.

Any help as to why it's doing this - as I can't seem to understand why - would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, you have used `input.nextDouble` method, which reads only the next token in the input, thus skipping the `newline` at the end. See [Scanner.nextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)

Now, if you enter wrong value first time, then it will consider the `newline` as the next input. Which will also be invalid.

You can add an empty `input.nextLine` in the catch block.

```
catch(Exception wrongType){
    System.err.println(wrongType);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.  Start again!!");
    i=0;
    input.nextLine();  // So that it consumes the newline left over
}
```

Now, your `nextLine()` will read the `linefeed` left over, and linefeed will not be taken as input to your `nextDouble` next time. In which case, it will fail, even before you giving any input.

Comment: That would only happen if it reaches the catch block though.  I need it to set it to 0 if it reaches the catch block, but what I'm asking is why it keeps looping through once I enter an invalid value instead of waiting for the user to enter another value.  Thank you for your response :)

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm asking.  It doesn't stop for the user to enter another value.

Comment: It will allow the user to enter the next value. But till then your `catch` block will get executed twice.

Comment: Sorry, done it now, when I first clicked on it I had to do it in 6 minutes, and so i waited but then forgot :p all is done now! thank you again :)